# Split string type Series according to given vocabularies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with multiple units. See below:

```py
units_col = pd.Series([
'mcg',
'ml',
'usec',
'kg',
'hour',
'mol'
])
```

I would like to identify the components of these units. This is prefix + base unit. For example:
Miligram -> 'mg' = 'm' + 'g'
Microliter -> 'mcl' = 'mc' + 'l'.

For this, I have created 2 lists:

```
prefixes = ['u','mc','m','d','k']
base_units = ['g','l','sec','mol','eq','ph','hour']
```

How can I produce the result below?

```
split_units = pd.Series([
['mc','g'],
['m','l'],
['u','sec'],
['k','g'],
['hour'], *
['mol'] *
])
```

Note 'hour' and 'mol' above are not prefixed.

I have tried doing below:

```
split_units = units_col.apply('function that does a double for loop, iterating on both lists')
```

But this is slow and not very scalable. Above is a vanilla example. I have around 20 prefixes and 100 base units. Column 'units_col' above has 500 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
units_col = pd.Series(["mcg", "ml", "usec", "kg", "hour", "mol"])

prefixes = ["u", "mc", "m", "d", "k"]
base_units = ["g", "l", "sec", "mol", "eq", "ph", "hour"]

r = "(" + "|".join(prefixes) + ")?(" + "|".join(base_units) + ")"

print(units_col.str.extract(r).apply(lambda x: list(x[x.notna()]), axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
0     [mc, g]
1      [m, l]
2    [u, sec]
3      [k, g]
4      [hour]
5       [mol]
dtype: object
```